# Postgres Like to Full Text Search

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I attempting to create a query to find the name `other` in my sql database. I have a basic like search as follow and would like to use a full text search instead.

Like Query

```
SELECT g.*, COUNT(*) OVER() AS total 
FROM group AS g 
WHERE UPPER(g.name) LIKE UPPER('oth%')
```

Full Text Query

```
SELECT g.*, COUNT(*) OVER() AS total 
FROM group AS g 
WHERE to_tsvector(g.name) @@ to_tsquery('oth:*')
```

It appears that my full text returns 0 unlike  my like search does. Why is this so when it appears that both queries appear to be doing similar searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 'other' is in the default stop word list in english.
I have tested with PostgreSQL 12 at Linux level:

```
$ grep other /usr/pgsql-12/share/tsearch_data/english.stop 
other
```

In the database:

```
postgres=# select to_tsvector('french','other');
 to_tsvector 
-------------
 'other':1
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_tsvector('english','other');
 to_tsvector 
-------------

(1 row)

postgres=# select to_tsvector('english','others');
 to_tsvector 
-------------
 'other':1
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_tsvector('english','another');
 to_tsvector 
-------------
 'anoth':1
(1 row)
```

Try 'another'.